# Android Service and thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Is a "Service" in android same as a separate thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) javadoc:

> Note that services, like other
>   application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process.

So the answer is No.

Comment: @Arun : take some time to go through the documents, they are sufficiently detailed and come directly from source.

Answer (score 1):

A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.
A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).